# How to search multiple columns with priority in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

I currently have a PHP function (codeigniter) which takes a query string (from post), and returns relevant MySQL rows, like this:

```
$term = $this->input->post("query");
$rows = $this->db->query("SELECT id, title as 'desc' , abbreviation , etc FROM shows WHERE abbreviation LIKE '%".$term."%' OR title LIKE '%".$term."%' OR etc LIKE '%".$term."%'  LIMIT 10; ")->result_array();
```

this works, but lets say my table is like this :

```
id  title                    abbreviation
--  ----------------------   ------------
1   The Big Bang Theory      TBBT
2   How I Met Your Mother    HMYM
3   a show called tbbt hmym  ASCTM
```

Now, when the user searches for `tbbt`, it returns 3rd row first. But I want the abbreviation to be the "main" parameter.

So if abbreviation matches, return it first, then look for the title column.

I think I can do it with PHP, like this:

```
// pseudo-code : 
$abbreviation_matches = result("bla bla WHERE abbreviation LIKE term AND NOT title like term");
$title_matches = result("bla bla WHERE NOT abbreviation LIKE term AND title LIKE term");
$result = append($abbreviation_matches , $title_matches);
```

But I'm afraid this will not be so efficient, since it involves 2 separate SQL queries. So is there a more efficient way to do this? Preferrably in one query ?

And the real case is with 4 columns, but only one column has priority, so the other ones are not important in order.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be one of the solutions:

```
SELECT id, desc, abbreviation, etc FROM
( 
   SELECT 1 AS rnk,  id, title as 'desc' , abbreviation , etc FROM shows 
   WHERE abbreviation LIKE '%".$term."%'
   UNION 
   SELECT 2 AS rnk,  id, title as 'desc' , abbreviation , etc FROM shows 
   WHERE title LIKE '%".$term."%' 
) tab
ORDER BY rnk
LIMIT 10;
```

Or you can achieve the same by the following:

```
SELECT  id, desc, abbreviation, etc FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN abbreviation LIKE '%".$term."%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END As rnk,
    id, title AS desc, abbreviation, etc 
    FROM shows 
    WHERE abbreviation LIKE '%".$term."%' 
    OR title LIKE '%".$term."%' 
) tab
 ORDER BY rnk
 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: wow. seems great. more than I ask for, because I can use this rank even further, like 1,2,3 etc. But what about duplicate rows? Is this duplicate-safe ?

Comment: Use DISTINCT keyword in the SELECT of sub-query if you think that abbreviation or title column values might have duplicates in the data table. A word of caution, here the rnk column would only have value 1 or 2 only depending upon which column the match was found in. But in case you want to rank 1,2,3... your query results I would suggest you to put it in a separate question.

Comment: Yes of course I got the rank part. But no, my table does not have duplicate values. And now I read your code more carefully, and I think it will work fine. Just please let me test it and then accept your answer. Thanks again !

Comment: run it piecemeal. Try running the inner query first and see if it works fine or not

Comment: Oh, there was a wrong table name, now the code works fine. Thanks again !

Comment: The two solutions are not equivalent since in the first query, Union will not be able to clear duplicates because `rnk` will make similar requests distinctive.